# Mapping paddy rice fields with PMI(Paddy rice mapping index) with Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, remote-sensing

I would like to perform mapping paddy rice with the Google Earth Engine for large scale. I came across with an article which proposed method for mapping paddy rice with special index related to phenological characteristics of paddy rice. Here is link for research paper [www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/10/3/447/s1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKQP1.png).

According to this article they calculated PMI (Paddy rice Mapping Index) in two crop season, transplantin/seeding and harvest period. Based on this algorithm paddy rice is identified with more than 0.2 thereshold.
[image]

Thus, my goal is develop this algorithm in the Google earth engine Platform. I am going to this Multispectral Images such as Landsat and Sentinel-2. Here I wrote some codes but I recieved some error.
[image]

Please see my code below,

```
Map.centerObject(roi);

var spring = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA")
                          .filterDate('2020-05-20','2020-06-15')
                          .filterBounds(roi)
                          .map(function(image){return image.clip(roi)});

var harvest = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA")
                          .filterDate('2020-09-10','2020-09-30')
                          .filterBounds(roi)
                          .map(function(image){return image.clip(roi)});

/// PMI Identification

var spring_NIR = spring.select('B5')
var harvest_NIR = harvest.select('B5')

var numerator = harvest_NIR.subtract(spring_NIR);
var denominator = harvest_NIR.add(spring_NIR);
var PMI = numerator.divide(denominator);


var colors = ['white','yellow'];
Map.addLayer(PMI, {palette: colors}, 'Colored PMI');
```

Code link https://code.earthengine.google.com/2f096e88a9babe58c1e790d64af50642

Comment: I can't see your ROI, but I can infer the problem is that you are working with image collections. Both spring_NIR and harvest_NIR are image collections (you can check it out by print), if they were images the code would work fine. Do you really need to work with collections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to add/subtract Image Collections from each other. It is only possible to add/subtract single Images.

The solution would be to reduce down the Image Collection to single images. For example by using `.mean()` or `.first()`:

```
var spring = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA")
                          .filterDate('2020-05-20','2020-06-15')
                          .filterBounds(roi)
                          .map(function(image){return image.clip(roi)})
                          .first();

var harvest = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA")
                          .filterDate('2020-09-10','2020-09-30')
                          .filterBounds(roi)
                          .map(function(image){return image.clip(roi)})
                          .first();

/// PMI Identification

var spring_NIR = spring.select('B5')
var harvest_NIR = harvest.select('B5')

var numerator = harvest_NIR.subtract(spring_NIR);
var denominator = harvest_NIR.add(spring_NIR);
var PMI = numerator.divide(denominator);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for clarification.